# Circuits in use when time to re-boot

Tags: relays

The occasional re-boot is needed for updates and things. Do I need to somehow clear / stop current relay circuits prior to doing a reboot to keep from messing someone up? Or do it just do a tor service stop, reboot, and it will come back to life.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You just follow the normal way to stop tor (and start it after you reboot). When you stop tor, it will show you something like:

```
Jan 27 14:12:23.000 [notice] Interrupt: we have stopped accepting new connections, and will shut down in 30 seconds. Interrupt again to exit now.
```

This means, it is exiting 'gracefully'.

Comment: Ok thanks. I just wanted to make sure I didn't mess anyone up. Happy Tor'ing.

Comment: @John If this past solved your question you can accept it as the answer ;)